# Hello everybody? ios app with visual studio

Tags: xamarin

Hello everybody? I have problem with xamarin visual studio. I just started to develop ios app. But when I try to open Main.storyboard it doesn't launch view controller.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSNCp.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting

Comment: Please post your code as text no image

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Visual Studio doesn't do storyboards. If you want storyboard support, use Xcode, on a Mac. You can see that in the screenshot you posted: see the text at the top? "To edit iOS storyboards, you can use Xcode on a Mac."

However, it is best *not* to do that, as you will then have a split between the Android and iOS code; the idea of Xamarin is to use a kind of HTML layout that is interpreted in a cross-platform way.

Comment: So do i need mac for build ios app in visual studio? Can i build ios app only in windows?

Comment: That is not the question you asked. You asked why storyboards don't open and I told you why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio on your mac and install Xcode. Clicking on Main.storyboard will automatically jump to the Xcode interface.

Comment: So do i need mac for build ios app in visual studio? Can i build ios app only in windows?

Comment: Yes, you need to run on mac